# Examining sessions across servers

Tags: asp.net, session, iis

I have an ASP .net application hosted in server1 (win 2008 , IIS), on server 2  I have the same copy of that application (admin module), I have the session handled by ASP .net session handler. How can I determine who is loggedin In server1 app? 
I want to see the alive sessions on server2.

Comment: What is your effort on this ? show what you are trying...

Comment: I want to session out people on server1 from server2 admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing the session in a database that both app has access to.

Comment: Yes I can do this that way, but the current application design and what the client want is the way i described. we don't want any session related information stored in DB. Its a transactional system